# Consulta MySQL - python no devuelve registros

Tags: mysql, python

Tengo una consulta donde solicito todos los registros según la fecha del día actual.

Para eso le paso a una variable la fecha actual de la siguiente manera:

```
micurs= mydb.cursor()

fecha=datetime.date.today()

sql="SELECT sucursal.idsuc, sucursal.nomsu, procesos.entradas, 
procesos.salidas, procesos.fecha FROM sucursal INNER JOIN procesos ON 
sucursal.idsuc = procesos.idsuc WHERE procesos.fecha= %s "%fecha

micurs.execute(sql)

resultado= micurs.fetchall()
for row in resultado:
    print (row)


mydb.close()
```

Debería devolverme los datos solicitados pero se ejecuta sin devolver registros, estoy utilizando spyder para trabajar python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres sustituir el *placeholder* `%s` por el valor de la variable "fecha", usa `% (fecha,)`, con la coma después del nombre de la variable, para indicar que es una tupla.

```
sql="SELECT 
         sucursal.idsuc, 
         sucursal.nomsu, 
         procesos.entradas, 
         procesos.salidas, 
         procesos.fecha 
     FROM sucursal 
     INNER JOIN procesos 
          ON sucursal.idsuc = procesos.idsuc 
     WHERE procesos.fecha= %s " % (fecha,)
```

Esto sin olvidar que, sustituir una variable de esta manera para consultas a una base de datos, es poco recomendado por la inseguridad.

Si aún así sigue sin dar nada, ha de ser porque tu consulta no tiene nada registrado con la fecha actual. Intenta revisar tu consulta con tu cliente de `mysql` consulta por consulta, tabla por tabla para ver qué fechas tienes registradas y tal vez no quieras una igualdad sino un rango.

### Actualización 1

Por despistado no me percaté cuando mandas a obtener la fecha con `datetime`

```
fecha=datetime.date.today()
```

Para que salga una fecha, por ejemplo, de la forma `2019/05/16` haz uso del método `datetime.datetime.strftime`

```
> fecha=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.date.today(),'%Y/%m/%d')
> print(fecha)
2019/05/16
```

Para revisar, tanto este como el caso anterior, imprime tu consulta cuando ejecutes tu programa.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta pero realice el cambio y sigue sin devolver registros, incluso ingrese registros con la fecha actual y continua sin devolver registros

Comment: ¿Aún intentando correr la consulta en un cliente de `mysql`? Si no te aparece nada, quita el filtro `WHERE procesos.fecha` en tu cliente y ve depurando consulta por consulta. Es seguro que no es un problema con tu código de python, sino con tu consulta de mysql.

Comment: En la consulta si le indico de manera manual la fecha si devuelve registros, pero necesito pasarle un parametro con la fecha actual ya que necesito obtener registros con la fecha del dia actual y no logro hacerlo

Comment: Ya actualicé mi respuesta, intenta con `datetime.datetime.strftime(objeto_datetime, 'formato de salida')`

Comment: muchisimas gracias eso era lo que faltaba establecer el formato de la fecha